# Overlay problem

Tags: edit-mode

Well, I'm totally new user of this program, and I decided to use it only because I need to make an intro for my youtube videos.
I don't make it on my own, I downloaded template and replaced text only, but there is one problem.
The template has got overlay as a backround which doesn't show on my rendered video.
I got that overlay in my folder anyway.
Why is that so?
Please help.
How video should look like: http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=2zrgked%3E&s=8#.Vb4VuvmqpAE
My video: http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=2hztk4k%3E&s=8#.Vb4UKfmqpAE

Comment: Could you post a .blend file via pasteall.org ? We may see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably have to change the blendtype to alpha over. You can find it in the video sequence editor in the properties panel <kbd>N</kbd>, under the tab Edit strip.

[image]

Comment: @lazarus, if that doesn't work maybe you could upload your blendfile

Comment: Thanks!
Can you please help me to save it?Do I need to render it again? @gladys

Comment: @Lazarus, Upload your blendfile to some hosting service (e.g. pasteall or blendexchange) and put the link here. Then I can take a look. But i think you can just save it. Rendering is done in the render properties panel. Under the output tab, you choose a location were to save it, and you can choose the fileformat, for example H.264. And render the animation (in the render tab).